# Load ENV file from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, environment-variables

I have a bash script that has the following content :

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./django.dev.env
docker compose --env-file ./uvicorn.dev.env -f ./docker-compose.yaml
```

and a *django.dev.env* file with the following content:

```
REQUIREMENTS_FILE=/src/requirements/dev.txt
```

and in the *docker compose* command I use REQUIREMENTS_FILE env var, but it doesn't work and says can't find this var but if I change bash script file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export REQUIREMENTS_FILE=/src/requirements/dev.txt
docker compose --env-file ./uvicorn.dev.env -f ./docker-compose.yaml
```

it works very well but I should use an env file and I don't want hard coding vars in my bash script, there has any solution for this problem?

Comment: Because you omitted `export` in this ".env" file?

Comment: @TomYan hi, I add the export prefix for all env var in my env file like this `export DJANGO_IP="0.0.0.0"
export DJANGO_PORT=8181  ` and in my bash script only use source prefix of file env and its work thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you know the docker compose `--env-file` option, why don't you put  EQUIREMENTS_FILE also in env file?

1. i recommand use docker way manage env var, official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables
2. if you need bash way for some reason, i think you should write `export REQUIREMENTS_FILE=/src/requirements/dev.txt` in `django.dev.env`
3. if you can't or won't change `django.dev.env`, you can write bash script like below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o allexport
source ./django.dev.env
set +o allexport
docker compose --env-file ./uvicorn.dev.env -f ./docker-compose.yaml
```

links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs

Comment: hi, thanks it's working so good, I need it because I have to separate env vars for each service and in some services, some of the vars are sharing or common in some cases it is also needed when building images, I try to pass all env file with --env-file flag like this `docker compose --env-file first.env --env-file second.env .. ` but it took last of the file only, and I don't want to write all config of each service in a one file

Comment: update: one more way,  `export $(cat django.dev.env)` something like that